# Invalidating Django session in JS without access to the server

Tags: django, authentication, session-cookies, progressive-web-apps

I need the ability to invalidate the Django session even if there is no Internet connection (or the server is down, or anything). The session cookie is by default httpOnly, and I don't like to change it, so simply deleting it is not an option. Is there any standard way to deal with this issue?

The relatively simple solution is to write a custom middleware on top of Django sessions. This middleware could add a secondary session token, say `sessionid2`, that would be acessible (and deletable) from Javascript. Both would be checked simultanously, so just one missing would invalidate the session. However, I would strongly prefer to use some of-the-shelf solution, if one exists.

The application is supposed to work as Chrome's Progressive Web App, so I'll be happy with a Chrome-specific solution if there is one.

Comment: As per [this thread](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/268493/clear-session-using-javascript-function), seems you can't do this in Javascript per se, but you can using XmlHttpRequest/Ajax. Check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321232/ajax-django-login-authentication-without-re-direct) for additional reference.

Comment: @noogui Ajax is not an option, it requires connection to the server. Yes, I can't really remove the server side session this way, but it's ok. As long as the session cookie is safely destroyed, I don't care whether server knows or not.