# Django AJAX login without re-direct

Tags: django

Yes, there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18321232/ajax-django-login-authentication-without-re-direct) without resolution to the actual question.

My users may be trying out the app and then decide to register for an account to save. Once registered I need to log them in without redirecting or reloading the page. I've got the registration working and logging them in is no problem, but what do I return to the client in order for the logged in session to be active in the browser? I'm not looking to add any other frameworks or libraries to the stack, please.

Django View (some omitted)

```
class CheckAuthTokenAjaxView(FormView):

    form_class = AuthTokenForm

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(self.request.POST)

        u = get_user_model().objects.filter(email=email).first()
        u.email_confirmed = True
        u.save()

        login(self.request, u)

        # What should I be sending back?
        return JsonResponse({"success": True}, status=200)
```

JS

```
Doc.Register.checkAuthTokenForm = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = document.getElementById('authtoken-form');
    var data = new FormData(form);

    d3.json('/users/ajax/checkAuthToken/', {
        method: 'post',
        body: data,
        headers: {
            // "Content-type": "charset=UTF-8",
            "X-CSRFToken": Doc.CSRF,
        }
    })
    .then(result => {
        if (result.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // WHAT DO I DO HERE?
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can just save the auth token you receive from Django backend in the local storage and then use it in the subsequent calls.

In case you do get the token you'd also like to manipulate the UI to reflect the user has logged in, which you can update by updating the element relevant in the UI.

Comment: What is your `CheckAuthTokenAjaxView` mean to accomplish? Logging the user in or checking their current token? If you're logging the user in, then you should include the token generated for the session in your response.